RS485 ESD Protection
I am designing an RS485 interface and need to put ESD protection in place. For Power Supply I am adding a TVS between PWR and GND. For the A+ and B-, I am planning to do the same TVS to the GND. Is that a correct approach? I saw some sample schematics where TVS was added between A+ and B-, which I found confusing.

A TVS between A and B only makes sense if it's an isolated RS485
Those "712" asymmetrical TVSs are handy for RS485 data signals
(SM712 and several other brands making part names that rhyme)
If there's a possibility of connecting  +12 to black(gnd in) and ground to white (A or B) doing that will destroy the protection and the driver fairly easily. so you might want to add some sort of current limiter.

No it does not make sense only when isolated. RS-485 is never a two-wire bus. It's a three-wire bus with two data wires and a mandatory common reference between transceiver chips. Each transceiver chip will read the A and B signals in with respect to it's common ground terminal. Most chips allowing only +/- 7V common mode between chips. So in any case, it makes sense to protect A and B to the ground of the chip, not between A and B.

what would happen if you didn't connect the ground?

It is possible to use RS-485 without a ground connection but EMC performance is significantly degraded and such operation is not recommended. Most often what's meant by "isolated" is the transceiver has a local ground (isolated from the equipment via DC-DC and digital isolators), which must be referenced to the bus (usually labeled as ground or shield), and it is with respect to this ground that TVSs should be applied, if any. Differential input voltage is not usually limited so a differential TVS isn't important, only the normal mode ones (each line to local GND).

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Usually, most people that ask here why their RS-485 does not work, they have the common reference left disconnected, and have no other ground reference between circuits, such as earth. Floating 2-prong AC supplies make things even worse, having maybe tens of volts CM ripple.
